# How to push notification to android app, when new data is available at server?

Tags: android, publish-subscribe, android-jobscheduler

What i did is :

I have used `JobScheduler`.  In every two hours, it checks weather there is a new data available or not in `Server->Database->Table`. If new data available it retrieves the data and notifies to the subscriber.

Kindly any one suggest me weather this is right approach or not?

Is there any other way to do so?

Can I implement PUB/SUB concept here..
If yes, How?

I am using Godaddy Hosing..

Comment: No,it not a good way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,its not a good way

You may try like this

1) Integrate FCM Push notification at **Backend side**(PHP etc)

2) Take **Legacy Server Key** for Push notification from Firebase

3) Wherever you will get update of data send notification using **Device Token**

4)at app side you need to add code for handle push notification

for more help refer [this URL](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)